# What is the default version used by Knex.js for the mysql client when no value specified

Tags: mysql, knex.js

The Knex.js documentation allows for a `version` to be set when using a client, in my case I'm using `mysql`,  something like this:

```
  client: 'mysql',
  version: '5.7',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
});
```

If I don't specify a value for `version` what default value will it use?

Answer (score 1):

Per source code: <s>https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/client.js#L53</s> (looks like file changed locations: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/lib/client.js#L53)

"version" exists for reference only, whichever version of mysql you're connecting to will be used.

As for which versions of MySql that are supported by knex, I'd direct you to their docs: https://knexjs.org/

Comment: That statement does not appear in your link, but it seems likely enough. Hard to believe they would or even could shoot multiple versions at the client. Stupid misfeature.

Comment: The link I provided only references where "version" is initialized by the code you provided, however it's not used anywhere else in the source code (other than overridden in one unit test).

Comment: @Nutatello The answer makes sense, good to know the version value is only "reference". However, I was not able to find out from their documentation what version of MySql is supported from the knexjjs.org url.

Comment: @user207421 as knex is a querybuilder, I wouldn't imagine you'd run into version problems provided you're not using a deprecated version of MySql. I suggest using the latest stable version of MySql, I personally prefer the mysql2 client as well.

Comment: Actually there are some minor differences in generated queries depending on version of target DB. IIRC in schema builder datatypes. If version is not given it is parsed from databases response (in case of official mysql db, on non official mysql compatibles one has to pass the DB version manually to make sure that queries are built correctly)

Comment: @MikaelLepistö This is actually a great answer. If you feel it's valid, you could post this as an answer and I would mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I didn't make it as an answer because I didn't have time to make fact checks + get exact code references to back those claims... If someone has some time to do it, I don't mind if anyone else makes a proper answer out of it :)